# New operator outside main function - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

Why this code is working:

```
 //Things
 int **A;

 main(){

    //things
    A = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = new int[m];
        }
   // things
}
```

And this code isn't working:

```
//Things
int **A;

void functionOutsideMain(int **A,int n, int m){
    A = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = new int[m];
        }
    }

main(){

//Things
functionOutsideMain(A,n,m);
//Things
}
```

When I use **new** operator outside main function in a separate function it won't work.

But if I use **new** operator inside main funcion it works.

Can you explain me why this is happening?

or

If I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get a compiler error? A crash? The `main()` function should be, minimally, `int main()`.

Comment: When I try to initialize the Matrix with numbers, it crash uppon the first time a number is asigned to the matrix.

Comment: In both examples `m` and `n` are not defined, so this code can't compile. It's important to give a *complete* example.

Comment: Your first code sample is not "working" - the `int` return type of `main` is missing, and `n` and `m` are not declared. The second code sample has similar issues, but I suspect they're not what you mean to ask about. Please paste an exact example of code that actually demonstrates the issue you're facing, and explain as exactly as you can what is going wrong or not giving the results you expect.

Comment: You're also shadowing `A` in your function, so the global `A` never gets assigned in the function version. This is just one of a million reasons why global variables are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Something weird happened.

https://ideone.com/q59fwz
Yesterday this code crashed when running llenar(); function
And instead of using a function I just used code inside main (without function)
And today is working.

Comment: You are modifying a copy of the `A` parameter.  Maybe you want `*A = //...` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, `A` is just a global variable, which `main()` uses directly.

In the second example, `functionOutsideMain()` has its own `A` parameter which it uses, whereas `main()` still uses the global `A` variable instead.

`functionOutsideMain()` takes its `A` parameter **by value**.  When `main()` passes in the global `A` variable to `functionOutsideMain()`, a *copy* of that `A` is made, and so any value that `functionOutsideMain()` assigns to its `A` parameter will not be applied to the global `A` variable, which is why `main()` does not see the change.

To do what you are attempting, you need to have `functionOutsideMain()` take its `A` parameter **by reference** instead:

```
void functionOutsideMain(int** &A, int n, int m)
```

Now, any value `functionOutsideMain()` assigns to its `A` parameter will be assigned to the global `A` variable, and thus will be seen by `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I didn't get what you meant by not working, but the possible solutions to the problems could be

- No need to pass A again to functionOutsideMain since A is already global
- When you pass A to functionOutsideMain, the actual parameter A becomes the formal parameter A, and now here's the problem, in C there is only pass by value(unlike pass by reference in C++). So when you pass A to the function, a new pointer gets created in the function and when you allocate a chunk of memory to it, the new pointer points to that memory and not the old pointer that you are using in main function.

One possible solution for this would be

```
void function_outside_main(int ***A, int n, int m) {
    int **Aptr = (*A);
    // And then use Aptr to allocate memory as you did
}
```

Else don't pass A as function parameter since it's a global variable